# Need help to pull JSON data from API using Python and load it to SQL Table

Tags: python-3.x

Please can you help me in writing Python Logic to PullJSON data from an API and load it to SQL Table directly.

I have written this Python Code and It works fine with Flat JSON Structure but fails If JSON has a child array.

For Example, Sales can have a header record and multiple line records in a single JSON file attached. I am able to pull and load header data but failing to load line data.

Here is my existing Python Code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import pandas as pd

Endpoint = "https://api.cin7.com/api"
FullEndpointExtension = "/v1/SalesOrders?order=Id&page=1&rows=250"

User_name = "XXXXX"
Password_key = "YYYYYY"
Authentication = HTTPBasicAuth(User_name, Password_key)
try:
    response = requests.get(Endpoint + FullEndpointExtension, auth = Authentication)
    DataFrame= pd.read_json(response.text)
    DataFrame = DataFrame[['id','createdDate','modifiedDate','createdBy','processedBy','isApproved','reference','memberId','firstName','lastName','company','email','phone','mobile','fax','deliveryFirstName','deliveryLastName','deliveryCompany','deliveryAddress1','deliveryAddress2','deliveryCity','deliveryState','deliveryPostalCode','deliveryCountry','billingFirstName','billingLastName','billingCompany','billingAddress1','billingAddress2','billingCity','billingPostalCode','billingState','billingCountry','branchId','branchEmail','projectName','trackingCode','internalComments','productTotal','freightTotal','freightDescription','surcharge','surchargeDescription','discountTotal','discountDescription','total','currencyCode','currencyRate','currencySymbol','taxStatus','taxRate','source','isVoid','memberEmail','memberCostCenter','memberAlternativeTaxRate','costCenter','alternativeTaxRate','estimatedDeliveryDate','salesPersonId','salesPersonEmail','paymentTerms','customerOrderNo','voucherCode','deliveryInstructions','status','stage','invoiceDate','invoiceNumber','dispatchedDate','logisticsCarrier','logisticsStatus','distributionBranchId','lineItems']]

#Capture Error Message
except Exception as ErrorMessage:
    Message = str(ErrorMessage)
    print(Message)
else:
    Message = 'Successfully Completed'
    print(Message)
    
DataFrame 


Sample code:
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/events")
DataFrame= pd.read_json(StringIO(response.text))

for I in DataFrame['actor']:
    print(DataFrame['id'],I['id'],I['login'])
```

Sample JSON:
[
{
"id": 111,
"createdDate": "2020-09-08T17:58:00Z",
"modifiedDate": "2020-09-10T02:01:09Z",
"createdBy": 0,
"processedBy": 99999,
"isApproved": true,
"reference": "4000000000",
"memberId": 1111,
"firstName": "RAM",
"lastName": "Live Credit Card Order",
"company": "",
"email": "ram@abc.co.nz",
"phone": "041411111",
"mobile": "",
"fax": "",
"deliveryFirstName": "Ram",
"deliveryLastName": "Live Credit Card Order",
"deliveryCompany": "",
"deliveryAddress1": "XXXX",
"deliveryAddress2": " ",
"deliveryCity": "XXXXX",
"deliveryState": "QLD",
"deliveryPostalCode": "XXXXX",
"deliveryCountry": "Australia",
"billingFirstName": "Ram",
"billingLastName": "Live Credit Card Order",
"billingCompany": "",
"billingAddress1": "XXXXXX",
"billingAddress2": "",
"billingCity": "XXXXXX",
"billingPostalCode": "XXXX",
"billingState": "QLD",
"billingCountry": "Australia",
"branchId": 3,
"branchEmail": "",
"projectName": "ABC",
"trackingCode": "",
"internalComments": "",
"productTotal": 29.9500,
"freightTotal": 0.0000,
"freightDescription": "",
"surcharge": 0.0000,
"surchargeDescription": "",
"discountTotal": 0.0000,
"discountDescription": "",
"total": 29.9500,
"currencyCode": "AUD",
"currencyRate": 1.0,
"currencySymbol": "$",
"taxStatus": "Incl",
"taxRate": 0.1,
"source": "API",
"customFields": {
"orders_1000": null,
"orders_1001": null,
"orders_1002": null,
"orders_1003": null,
"orders_1004": null
},
"isVoid": false,
"memberEmail": "ram@abc.co.nz",
"memberCostCenter": null,
"memberAlternativeTaxRate": null,
"costCenter": "",
"alternativeTaxRate": "",
"estimatedDeliveryDate": null,
"salesPersonId": 0,
"salesPersonEmail": null,
"paymentTerms": "",
"customerOrderNo": "",
"voucherCode": null,
"deliveryInstructions": "Please leave at reception",
"status": "APPROVED",
"stage": "Dispatched",
"invoiceDate": "2020-09-08T17:58:00Z",
"invoiceNumber": 5011111,
"dispatchedDate": "2020-09-08T20:31:00Z",
"logisticsCarrier": "BCD",
"logisticsStatus": 10,
"distributionBranchId": 0,
"lineItems": [
{
"id": 363,
"createdDate": "2020-09-08T17:58:00Z",
"transactionId": 267777,
"parentId": 199999,
"productId": 4444,
"productOptionId": 333333,
"integrationRef": "0",
"sort": 1,
"code": "T02392",
"name": "Mat Grey",
"option1": "",
"option2": "",
"option3": "",
"qty": 1.0,
"styleCode": "T02392",
"barcode": null,
"sizeCodes": null,
"lineComments": "",
"unitCost": 11.9900,
"unitPrice": 14.9500,
"discount": 0.0000,
"qtyShipped": 1.0,
"holdingQty": 0.0,
"accountCode": "",
"stockControl": "FIFO",
"stockMovements": [
{
"batch": null,
"quantity": 1.0,
"serial": null
}
],
"sizes": []
},
{
"id": 365,
"createdDate": "2020-09-08T17:58:00Z",
"transactionId": 267777,
"parentId": 199999,
"productId": 4444,
"productOptionId": 333333,
"integrationRef": "0",
"sort": 1,
"code": "A1111",
"name": "Mat Grey",
"option1": "",
"option2": "",
"option3": "",
"qty": 1.0,
"styleCode": "ABCXYZ",
"barcode": "",
"sizeCodes": null,
"lineComments": "",
"unitCost": 11.9900,
"unitPrice": 0.0000,
"discount": 0.0000,
"qtyShipped": 1.0,
"holdingQty": 0.0,
"accountCode": "",
"stockControl": "Batch",
"stockMovements": [
{
"batch": "100",
"quantity": 1.0,
"serial": null
}
],
"sizes": []
},
{
"id": 364,
"createdDate": "2020-09-08T17:58:00Z",
"transactionId": 2641,
"parentId": 0,
"productId": 4410,
"productOptionId": 4411,
"integrationRef": "0",
"sort": 2,
"code": "DELIVERYFEE",
"name": "DELIVERYFEE",
"option1": "",
"option2": "",
"option3": "",
"qty": 1.0,
"styleCode": "DeliveryFee",
"barcode": "",
"sizeCodes": null,
"lineComments": "",
"unitCost": 0.0000,
"unitPrice": 8.0000,
"discount": 0.0000,
"qtyShipped": 1.0,
"holdingQty": 0.0,
"accountCode": "ABCXYZ",
"stockControl": "ABCXYZ",
"stockMovements": [],
"sizes": []
}
]
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved id:

```js
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import json_normalize
#https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html
#https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas

Endpoint = "https://api.cin7.com/api"
FullEndpointExtension = "/v1/SalesOrders?where=id=2666&order=Id&page=1&rows=250"

User_name = "xxxxxx"
Password_key = "xxxxxxx"
Authentication = HTTPBasicAuth(User_name, Password_key)
r = requests.get(Endpoint + FullEndpointExtension, auth = Authentication)

d = json.loads(r.text)

result1=json_normalize(data=d, record_path='lineItems', meta=['id'],errors='ignore', meta_prefix='Header')
print(result1)
```